# Rsnapshot made my external disk run out of space

Tags: rsync, hard-link, rsnapshot

I have Rsnapshot doing incremental backups from Client1 to Server1 (RAID 5) within folder "BACKUP".

On Server 1, tonight, I copied the "BACKUP"to an external disk for the first time using the command `rsync -av --whole-file --delete /home/Server1/Backup /mnt/zeusExt/Server1/Backup`. The command aborted on "Disk Full", even though the RAID on Server1 is 4TB and the external disk is also 4TB.

So I decided to do a `du -h` on the "BACKUP" folder (1.2TB) on the RAID and on the "BACKUP" folder on the external disk (492GB).

As you can see, the two sizes are not matching. Any clues as to why this may be? Is this to do with the hard links business that Rsnapshot uses? Is there a way to replicate the "BACKUP" folder on Server1 to its equivalent on the external disk using rsync (I guess there must be some option that I'm missing ...)?

Thanks

Comment: If it's hardlinks, then add `rsync -H` (preserve hard links). There's also -S sparse, -A ACL, -X extended attributes ...